# how to show a specific word in a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has various columns. One of them is called APP_DATA, and its fields are like this:
`s:12:"project_code";s:4:"1025";s:18:"project_code_label";s:4:"1025"`

I want to have a result that the output shows just project_code in the fields( not the other things)

I wrote a query like this:

```
 SELECT A.APP_DATA AS app_data,ACV.APP_NUMBER AS app_number, 
        ACV.APP_STATUS AS app_status 
        FROM APP_CACHE_VIEW AS ACV 
        LEFT JOIN APPLICATION AS A ON 
       ACV.APP_NUMBER = A.APP_NUMBER
       WHERE A.APP_DATA LIKE '%project_code%'
```

Unfortunately, the output of my query shows all of contents of APP_DATA. I like to have just a specific word!(just project_code)

How can I solve it?

Looking forward to your response

Comment: Is the data in `APP_DATA` a result of [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the expected output? I take for granted that you don't really want the `project_code` string.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use `SUBSTRING`.

Example:

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING(A.APP_DATA, 7, 12) AS app_data,ACV.APP_NUMBER AS app_number, 
    ACV.APP_STATUS AS app_status 
    FROM APP_CACHE_VIEW AS ACV 
    LEFT JOIN APPLICATION AS A ON 
   ACV.APP_NUMBER = A.APP_NUMBER
   WHERE A.APP_DATA LIKE '%project_code%'
```

[Example link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/query/mysql-substring/#5)

Careful, the index starts from 1.

> For all forms of SUBSTRING(), the position of the first character in the string from which the substring is to be extracted is reckoned as 1.

Comment: What is the difference between `SUBSTRING` and `SUBSTR`?

Comment: If returning the string "project_code" is what you want, you could as well just use `SELECT 'project_code' as app_data ...`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem is that, the length of fields is not equal. I mean, if I use a query like your example, I can not achieve what I want. the lengths of project_code are distinct. How can I solve it?

Comment: @mohamad Then instead of SUBSTR try to use RegEx, check the manual for examples.

Comment: @DonJoe According to the manual, there is no difference. They do the same thing